# Adding fade to this script?

Tags: jquery

How do i add fadeIn and fadeOut to this script? So when you press arrowr or arrowl the text will fadeout and fadein

When i try to do it, it wont work correctly.

```
var all = $('.img').addClass("passiv");

var i = -1;

$('#arrowl').click(function() {
    ctrlKunder( i = !i ? all.length - 1 : --i );
});
$('#arrowr').click(function() {
    ctrlKunder( i = ++i % all.length );
}).click();

function ctrlKunder(ele) {
    all.removeClass("active").addClass("passiv");
    all.eq(ele).removeClass("passiv").addClass("active");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6sMSG/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the class to show and hide, just handle it directly:

```
function ctrlKunder(ele) {
    all.fadeOut(1000);
    all.eq(ele).delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6sMSG/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the function ctrlKunder()
with this

```
function ctrlKunder(ele) {
  all.hide().fadeOut();
  all.eq(ele).fadeIn();
}
```